# How to specify and offset for select query on a table?

Tags: pact, pact-lang

Is it possible to specify an offset for select query on a table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently supported. Some alternatives are below. But they depend on the use-case

- Adding an index field to tables and querying on that range
- Using something like timestamps to filter results
- Indexing all the results in your own SQL table